# due to kanji variants, are 器械、海外、劍道 even words?

Tags: kanji

I am interested in kanji variants. Please consider these three variant pairs:

(normal kanji) 剣 ---> (variant) 劍
(normal kanji) 海 ---> (variant) 海
(normal kanji) 器 ---> (variant) 器

Are「劍道」、「海外」、「器械」even considered words? Or, for native speakers, are kanji variants a not so important side-note to the language?

If native speakers do pay some attention to kanji variants, then do the definitions change at all?
「剣道{けんどう}」の定義{ていぎ} = 「劍道」の定義?
「海外{かいがい}」の定義 = 「海外」の定義?
「器械{きかい}」の定義 = 「器械」の定義?

How do you say "kanji variant" in Japanese?
Are kanji variants tested for on 漢字検定試験？What level?

Comment: For kanji variants you're probably looking at [some mixture of 異体字, 旧字体, or others](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AD%97%E4%BD%93).

Comment:     ,            .              .

Comment: @blutorange Your point has zoomed right over my head. Your comparing changing the font to using a variant is wrong. "Does 'god' = 'God'" is a close example. Upper and lower case "god" are the same basic idea, but the case assigns attributes. So, does using a variant assign attributes? Would a good dictionary have definitions for each?

Comment: @user312440 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackletter

Comment: blutorange made a good point, but perhaps spelling differences would be a more accurate comparison: there are olde spelyngs, and then there are regional spellings, like color/colour. None of these change the meanings of words, and dictionaries will note the different forms, then go on to give one definition of the meaning.

Comment: @Brian Chandler Good point. A different script is to use a variant form considered to be the same conceptual character or glyph. A different spelling is the use of different character(s) or glyph(s) to write a word. So technically, it boils down to whether [Unicode did it right.](http://web.archive.org/web/20090627072117/http://www.jbrowse.com/text/unij.html) Not that it matters, it's just a comparison to help people relate to the issue better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More precisely, they are older forms ([旧字体]{きゅうじたい}) of kanji, rather than variants.

Japanese kanji went through an artificial simplification conducted by the government in 1950s. Now old forms are no longer in use, except occasionally in proper nouns they could be used for the purpose of kind of characterizing or "flavoring" the names. Most people can still read them, but no one uses them in their daily writings or printings. Schools no longer teach them either.

You can learn details about the simplification here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinjitai

Comment: I wasn't quite sure if you were right, because the printing of some of this characters in pre-WW2 books looked like the 新字体 to me, but  per http://www.benricho.org/moji_conv/14_shin_kyu_kanji.html you're exactly right.

Comment: Yes, in fact there had been a certain amount of naturally-generated simplified forms before the 新字体, and some of the 新字体 forms are just taken from them.